# 2002 Ford Focus CEL blinked for a minute and then turned off

Tags: engine, electrical, ford, cel

I have a 2002 Ford Focus with around 100k miles on it. I just brought it back from the mechanic for a fuel pump replacement. As [**this**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/is-my-mechanic-ripping-me-off/2738#2738) question shows.

Anyway I was driving around going uphill when I realized that I wasn't accelerating anymore. It was then that the check engine light started blinking for like 2 minutes and then turned off.

When I was done the hill after the stop sign, it started working again like normal.

Anyway I was 1/2 mile from my house so I brought it home. By that point the car was pretty jerky like it was about to stall.

Does the CEL doing that tell me anything? Also does it sound like theres something really bad wrong with my car, or is it related to the fuel pump?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blinking CEL is on this car is an indication of a misfire.  It sounds like you either have a bad or misconnected coil or spark plug.

This is a problem that needs to get solved but I don't think it's likely a consequence of the fuel pump replacement.

Try visually inspecting the coil and spark plug wires.  Look for grey streaks for places where your spark is escaping from its proper electrical path.

Note: if it's just spark plug wires, those are quite easy to replace and not costly in the bargain.